# prlimit not found centos6.3

Tags: linux, centos, ulimit

After finding out that [ulimit -m](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129587/does-ulimit-m-not-work-on-modern-linux/129592#129592) no longer does *anything* on linux... I am now investigating the use of `prlimit`.

I have found that this is supposed to exists as part of `util-linux` / `util-linux-ng`, I have this installed on my system, however

```
find / -name prlimit
```

Yields zero results; I currently have installed

> util-linux-ng.x86_64 0:2.17.2-12.7.el6_3

I have tried running

> yum update util-linux-ng

Which brought me to version

> 2.17.2-12.18.0.1.el6

With still the same issue; I am running CenotOS 6.3, upgrading is not an option.

Comment: `prlimit` is only in [`util-linux 2.21`](http://karelzak.blogspot.de/2012/01/prlimit1.html), so it's not available for CentOS 6.

Comment: This page states `supported since Linux 2.6.36`, My current kernel is `2.6.39`, am I still missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix up a syscall with a user space command. `prlimit(1)` the user space program was added to `util-linux 2.21` to make use of the `prlimit(2)` syscall available since Linux kernel 2.6.36. BTW, the default kernel on CentOS 6 is 2.6.32.